# Arabic is not regonized in my web application

Tags: java, web, collation, arabic

Im facing a problem with my web application. I have Arabic data stored in Microsoft SQL server 2005 and the server collation is Arabic_CI_AS and the data stored correctly but when im trying to view the data in my web application in java forms it appears like this:
 [image]

Comment: Change language encoding for the project. if you use Eclipse, you need to change the stdout encoding to UTF-8 :  Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Text File Encoding.